# JS testing a middleware is returning next()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, middleware, sinon, restify

I have a middleware class like this

```
// code.js
function validation(req, res, next) {
    if (validationLogic(req)) {
        res.send(400);
        return next(false);
    }
    return next();
}

// code.test.js
describe('validation', () => {
    describe('when req is valid', () => {
        //setting up req, res, next stub

        //some other test

        //HERE IS MY QUESTION, how do I text that validation returns next(), and not next(false)
        it('return next(), and next() is called exactly once', () => {
            const spy = sinon.spy();
            nextStub = spy;
            const result = validation(reqStub, resStub, nextStub);
            assert(spy.calledOnceWithExactly());
            assert(result === nextStub()); // both of this
            assert(result === nextStub(false)); // and this line passed
        });
    });
});
```

I was trying to test if my `validation` function is returning `next()` and not `next(false)`. But in the test, it looks like only `assert(spy.calledOnceWithExactly())` can test the parameter in `next`. But the line that follow `assert(result === nextStub())` cannot test anything beside that the result is actually from the function `next()`

Is `assert(spy.calledOnceWithExactly())` sufficient or, is there another way to test it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a spy.  You could always create a "placeholder" function that accepts an argument and substitute it in for next, and make sure that the function didn't return `false`

```js
it('return next(), and next() is called exactly once', () => {
    const nextStub = (arg) => (arg === false ? arg : 'I was called!');
    const result = validation(reqStub, resStub, nextStub);
    
    assert(result !== false);
    assert(result === 'I was called!');
});
```

Something like that might work. Or if you really want to use a spy, you can check both the return value of the spy and what the spy was called with. Make sure your spy function can accept arguments.

https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.0.0/spy-call/

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to approach this is to use an [`expectation`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.0.0/mocks/#expectations) to verify that `next` was called once with the exact arguments and that the result is returned from `validation`:

```
it('return next(), and next() is called exactly once', () => {
  const expectation = sinon.mock().once().withExactArgs().returns('called with no args');
  nextStub = expectation;
  const result = validation(reqStub, resStub, nextStub);
  expectation.verify();  // SUCCESS
  assert(result === 'called with no args');  // SUCCESS
});
```